# MUI X ChartBar Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `axisData.x.value` supplied to `ChartsAxisTooltipContent`, expected one of type [number]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bar-chart, mui-x, mui-x-charts

Like in the title, I got this warning when using MUI X ChartBar in my React app.
I followed the same thing as the document shown in the second bar example: https://mui.com/x/react-charts/bars/

How to solve this?

This is my code

```js
const [MonthlyJoinLibrary, setMonthlyJoinLibrary] = useState([])

<BarChart
 width={window.innerWidth - 55}
 height={450}
 dataset={MonthlyJoinLibrary}
 xAxis={[{ scaleType: 'band', dataKey: 'date', dateFormatter }]}
 series={[
  { dataKey: 'male_student', label: 'សិស្សប្រុស', color:"blue", valueFormatter},
  { dataKey: 'female_student', label: 'សិស្សស្រី', color:"red", valueFormatter},
  { dataKey: 'male_teacher', label: 'គ្រូប្រុស', color:"aqua", valueFormatter},
  { dataKey: 'female_teacher', label: 'គ្រូស្រី', color:"rgb(255,150,80)", valueFormatter},
 ]}
/>
```

Warning Output: [image]

I tried searching for a solution but still can't find a way to solve it.
I expect there will be no warning output.

Comment: The code is working fine. It's just that the warning is spamming in the console and I don't know why.

Comment: It's the same issue even in there default examples. If you open the codesandbox example and check its terminal, you will see the same warning.

Comment: Is it a normal thing that happened?

Comment: Does my app safe leaving it just like that?

Comment: Yes, it's just a warning for the type check that is failing. Maybe they fix it in later releases.

Comment: @GoodDay Same issue did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Sanmeet not yet I just leave it as it be.

Comment: @GoodDay I am facing it myself and  feels really horrible to see log of errors just to checkout other stuff in console . Let me know if you find any solution :-)

Comment: @Sanmeet not sure if this a solution. Somehow the warning is gone when I build it in production mode.

Comment: @GoodDay I've been following this issue on Github and this seems like a temporary fix. You might want to check out the [thread](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/11679#issuecomment-1902682837)